# How does the north-bridge (or analogous hardware) route memory reads and writes?

Tags: computer-architecture, bus

I would be tempted to think that there is some kind of parallel cache-line kind of mechanism, that works on registers that are set by the north-bridge drivers. But then, most architectures only allow hot-plugging into the PCI/e/ISA bus, but not into the overall memory address space, right ? So a set of permanent addresses are hard-coded perhaps? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, not hard-coded.

Memory is only reconfigured with the power off. Upon power-on, some of the very first code that the BIOS executes probes the memory slots to see what they contain. It then writes values into configuration registers in the bridge chip(s) that map the available memory into the address space of the CPU.

Comment: The actual process is pretty complicated on a modern PC, BIOS needs to initialize the memory controller and "train the memory" if the memory is newly installed (finding suitable operating parameters for the RAM). If the OP is curious, just watch this video [Coreboot: x86 system boot and initialization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xc08SN6Dhz4), it presents a step by step procedure with a descriptions of various steps (DRAM init, Northbridge/Southbridge init) necessary to bring the system to point where it can boot OS, using the free and open source coreboot as an example.